# Powershell Regex to Remove text block

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a printer GPD file that I'm trying to manipulate with powershell. In the "*Feature: PaperSize" block I need to fully remove Option 1 through Option 5. I've been trying regex lookbehind/ahead without success. Any ideas how to do this with Win10 built-in powershell functionality?

Here's the full paste.
https://pastebin.com/j2zSjaid

Here's the relevant section:

```
*Feature: PaperSize
{
    *rcNameID: =PAPER_SIZE_DISPLAY
    *DefaultOption: Option6
    *Option: Option1
    {
        *rcNameID: =IDS_PAPERNAME_A4
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(604205, 854518)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(604128, 854224)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(0, 0)
    }
    *Option: Option2
    {
        *rcNameID: =IDS_PAPERNAME_LETTER
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(621180, 803880)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(621180, 803880)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(0, 0)
    }
    *Option: Option3
    {
        *rcNameID: =IDS_PAPERNAME_POSTCARD
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(287717, 425820)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(287448, 425488)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(0, 0)
    }
    *Option: Option4
    {
        *rcNameID: =IDS_PAPERNAME_58_297
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(166876, 854518)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(146160, 854224)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(10962, 0)
    }
    *Option: Option5
    {
        *rcNameID: =IDS_PAPERNAME_58_3276
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(166876, 9425594)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(146160, 9425290)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(10962, 0)
    }
    *Option: Option6
    {
        *rcNameID: =IDS_PAPERNAME_80_297
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(230173, 854518)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(207872, 854224)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(10962, 0)
    }
    *Option: Option7
    {
        *rcNameID: =IDS_PAPERNAME_80_3276
        *PageDimensions: PAIR(230173, 9425594)
        *PrintableArea: PAIR(207872, 9425290)
        *PrintableOrigin: PAIR(10962, 0)
    }
    *Option: CUSTOMSIZE
    {
        *rcNameID: =USER_DEFINED_SIZE_DISPLAY
        *MinSize: PAIR(3, 3)
        *MaxSize: PAIR(9425594, 9425594)
        *MaxPrintableWidth: 9425594
        *MinLeftMargin: 0
        *TopMargin: 0
        *BottomMargin: 0
        *CenterPrintable?: FALSE
        *CursorOrigin: PAIR(0, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you count on the following number of lines to always be 6 including the braces?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the prettiest, but it will make sure to only grab lines from Option1 through body of Option5 in the PaperSize feature section.

```
$text -replace '(?s)(?<=Feature: PaperSize.+)\s+\*option: Option1.+(?=\r?\n.+tion: Option6)'
```

It seems you already know about look ahead/behind so I'll just highlight a few important pieces.

**`(?s)`** says to treat all the text like a single line. This allows `.` to match newline characters.

**`(?<=)`** Positive look behind. This ensures the match must follow `Feature: Papersize.+`

**`(\*)`** Literal asterisk.

**`(\r?\n)`** Matches a newline in powershell.

And the call to `-replace` without a second argument. It's the same as adding `,''` - just replace the match with nothing.